# QImage::fromData not thread safe

Tags: thread-safety, qthread, qimage

The following code crashes if run inside multiple QThreads:

```
//mutex.lock();
qImage = QImage::fromData((const uchar*)bin,size);
//mutex.unlock();
```

I can fix that with mutexes, but it defeats the purpose of multithreading. What would you advise?

Thanks

Comment: Why does that defeat the purpose of multithreading? If two threads are going into a critical section of the code that is demonstrably thread unsafe, then the mutexes (or similar synchronization entities) are required.

Comment: The purpose of the function was to use multiple threads to convert multiple binaries into bitmaps. Each thread has a perfectly independent task, so it should have worked. QImage::fromData is a static function and it is possible to make a static function which is not thread safe, but I don't understand why would they do that.

Comment: I wouldn't know why it behaves that way. I did notice however the sources for QT's QImage seem to be available [at this location.](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Get_The_Source) That might reveal why the issue exists and whether there are workarounds other than mutex usage. I understand your concern however. I work with a proprietary library that has a similar issue, with the same results. It causes unwanted bottlenecks in our multithread apps.